# Creating class objects with loops

Tags: c++, class, methods

I created a class Elevator with the public, private and protected variables. Also, I wrote some methods. Now a question how can I simplify these lines of code with objects announcement.

```
int main()
{
    Elevator ElevatorObject("NAME", 2, 3, 4, 5);
    ElevatorObject.get_name();
    ElevatorObject.get_loadCapacity();
    ElevatorObject.get_MotorPower();
    ElevatorObject.get_height();
    ElevatorObject.get_witdth();

    Elevator ElevatorObject1("NONAME", 5, 4, 3, 2);
    ElevatorObject1.get_name();
    ElevatorObject1.get_loadCapacity();
    ElevatorObject1.get_MotorPower();
    ElevatorObject1.get_height();
    ElevatorObject1.get_witdth();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am thinking to put all needed names of objects into a string array and then realize it in a loop. But then there will be the same values in object parameters.

Like this.

```
string ObjectName[3] = { "ElevatorObject1", "ElevatorObject2", "ElevatorObject3" };

int main()
{
    string ObjectName[3] = { "ElevatorObject1", "ElevatorObject2", "ElevatorObject3" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        Elevator ObjectName[i]("NEMA", 2, 3, 4, 5);
        ObjectName[i].get_name();
        ObjectName[i].get_loadCapacity();
        ObjectName[i].get_MotorPower();
        ObjectName[i].get_height();
        ObjectName[i].get_witdth();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

There is an error "C2131 the expression must have a constant value".
Maybe I made a mistake somewhere...

Comment: `Elevator ObjectName[i]("NEMA", 2, 3, 4, 5);` this means you are trying to create a new array each loop of size `i`

Comment: `ElevatorObject.get_name();` is strange. do you mean `print_name()`, `input_name()` ?

Answer (score 1):

This line makes no sense:

```
Elevator ObjectName[i]("NEMA", 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

You're calling as if you mean something like this:

```
Elevator "ElevatorObject1"("NEMA", 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Which is obviously not going to work. Instead you probably mean to supply the name:

```
Elevator elevator(ObjectName[i], 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

The name of the variable created should be something else entirely.

You probably mean to create a `std::vector` or `std::array` you can `push_back` into each time you create a new `Elevator` object.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Fixed. Thanks.